# How to design a Eclipse RCP (Client/Server) using EMF for the model?

Tags: eclipse, client-server, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf

We are planing a project where we will have an eclipse based client communicating with an glassfish server (+ Oracle database). The business logic will reside on the server, the client should act more or less as an view. We consider using EMF for our model (+ hibernate + teneo).

I'm not quite sure how this all works together. The workflow/architecture/whatever I imagine is something like this:

1. Create EMF model
2. Generate java model (+ edit code) from it
3. Use java model on the server together with hibernate/teneo to persist model objects in database
4. Create a SOAP interface in the server, serialize model objects to XML as appropriate
5. Use model on the client to access the SOAP interface of the server, serialize/deserialize model objects from/to XML and display (parts of the whole) model in eclipse

Is this basicly how it is intended? Or have I missed a central concept?

Comment: Yes, your workflow basically describes the process.  You want to make sure all of your SOAP calls from the RCP are in their own threads, and not in the UI thread, for UI responsiveness.

Comment: Take a look at Eclipse CDO. Its main purpose is the sharing of EMF Models on a server to several clients -> http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDO

Comment: From what I have read I can use Teneo (for more Server based applications) or CDO (if I want to have more buisness logic on the client). But use them together does not make sense ... right? Wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The link you are missing is called CDO. You can use this to transfer a live model to your client. So replace SOAP with CDO, and you are there!